# How can I assign unique IDs to DIVs generated from multidimensional array located in state of a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimentional array, based on the hirerchy of the array elements, I want to created exactly the same multilevel nested DIVs in React app. How can I assign unique IDs to DIVs generated from multidimensional array in React Component state so that whenever I click on particular div I should know which element of this multidimentional array needs to modified.

Following is the code I have written in to render DIVs as per Array located in component's state:

```
state = {
 arrSectionsContainer: [
                            ['A'], 
                            [
                                [
                                    ['D'], ['E']
                                ], 
                                ['C']
                            ]
                          ]
```

}

Function to render UI (UI is correctly rendered):

```
render() {
const {  arrSectionsContainer } = this.state;

const renderUI = (arrSectionsContainer, j) => {
    return (
        arrSectionsContainer.map((ele, i) => {
            if (ele.length === 1) {
                return (
                    <div id={`sectionDiv${i}${j}`}>Single Div - {i}</div>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {renderUI(ele, i)}
                       
                    </div>
                )

                renderUI(ele)
            }
        })
    )
}

return (
    <div>
        {renderUI(arrSectionsContainer, 0)}
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: what is the issue you face when you use id={`sectionDiv${i}${j}` ?

Comment: May I suggest using `id={\`sectionDiv-${i}-${j}\`}` so you can differentiate single digits from non-single digits between `i` and `j` indices. I.E is "sectionDiv111" `i == 1` and `j == 11` or is it `i == 11` and `j == 1`.

Comment: @Rohan - i and j works fine till array is nested upto 2 levels, when it becomes deeper, it gives the same i and j values due to recursion.

Comment: Right Drew, but still it does not solve the complete problem